# Python counter percentages returning 0

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, counter, percentage

I have a Counter of occurrences of items in a list here:

```
tldcount = Counter(tlds)
```

The output of this looks like:

```
Counter({'com': 4, 'co.uk': 2, 'gov.uk': 1})
```

I am trying to now return the percentages of these counts using this:

```
 percentage = [(i, tldcount[i] / len(tlds) * 100.0) for i in tldcount]
```

However, all percentages return as 0:

```
[('gov.uk', 0.0), ('com', 0.0), ('co.uk', 0.0)]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A piece of magic: `percentage = [(i, tldcount[i] * 100.0 / len(tlds)) for i in tldcount]` would do the thing.

Comment: In python 2, it's important to check divisions int / int, becase they will  solve as int (truncated)